# App designer not working for existing titanium apps - XML parse error

Tags: appcelerator, designer, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy, appcelerator-studio

I tried to use app designer with an existing app to see if it could render the views properly. However, when I open an existing view in app designer mode it shows the error

```
XML Parsing Error
Line : 1
Premature end of file.
```

I've tried this with a brand new project and it seems to work fine without error. I am also using the latest SDK with my old project (5.4.0).

Another thing I wanted to try was using the "Movies" demo app with the app designer and it didn't have an error but it did show a blank page and only when you turned on "Show Anchors" from the toolbar did it show some outlines of controls but they were not in the correct places.

Hopefully someone has some ideas but it seems to me this only works with brand new projects for some reason.

I've looked in the studio log files too and there's no entry for app designer when I use it and see this error message.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: It looks like it tries to read an XML configuration that does not exist.

Comment: Yeah, wondering why it doesn't work for an existing app that does have a view? The view is very simple though, just has the <Alloy> tags and that is it. Any idea how I can look into this further? Thanks

Comment: Can you provide a sample view file with a reproducible code - so that I can help you on that.

Comment: Hi Kondal, thanks for taking the time. The view I am trying this with only has <Alloy> tags and nothing else. I've tried this with existing views in my project and added a new view file just to see if this would show me something but unfortunately it doesn't? 

Do you think there is some config missing since this is an old project and it seems to work on a new project?

Comment: @rsmacfarlane88 -  I think your view is having some CR-LF(Carriage returns and line feeds) characters and that was causing XML parse error. Just to experiment, paste all view file content into some plain notepad and put it back.

Comment: @KondalKolipaka thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately this didn't work. I realise I'm not helping anyone help me if I can't give code examples but it really is just a new empty view in an existing project that we've had for a couple of years. I'll raise a JIRA ticket with appcelerator and see how it goes. Thanks again